Как добавить загрузчик uefi или bios на gt-p5210?
Есть планшет gt-p5210 с процесором intel atom z2560 на x86 архитектуре, с установленным андроидом на борту. Есть желание поставить загрузчик uefi либо bios, что бы накатить винду на него или хотя бы попытаться изучив данную тему. Есть советы куда копать и откуда черпать информацию ?
